# Do I need to include entire SDWebImage library for image downloading in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to use the "SDWebImage" library in my iOS application in which I am using an UICollectionView to display a number of images.

**Do I need to add all the files from SDWebImage library to my project?** I learnt that I just need to import the **UIImageview+webcache** category in my view controller to start the image download. Please give your inputs.

Comment: Open the category and see what dependencies (`#import`s) it has - you will need these dependencies in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice would be to install it through Cocoapods: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage#installation-with-cocoapods

That way, you won't have to worry about dependencies and you will just need to use

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

anywhere you need it

Comment: But, one concern!! Even if I install via cocoapods, it will always add the entire library. Is there anyway I can add only the files which are required to import UIImageView+WebCache.h?.

Comment: If you import in your project all the files needed in cascade it should work. But there is no good reason to do that, since the compiler will only take the code actually used. Your app download size will not change.

Comment: Ok Thanks! It's always the ideal way